# Set up App Pool per publication(country)

Tags: configuration

Currently we have single app pool for all the sites(publication/country).
Now requirement is to give separate app pool per publication/country.
The problem is how to resolve the common references for per publication.

Thanks,
Khemchand.

Comment: what exactly makes this a Tridion related question? and why would you need a separate app pool per publication/country, isn't that way too much overhead in memory? Please edit your question and provide some more information, because in its current state it is a bit difficult to gve a good answer.

Comment: What you describe as a requirement is actually a choice of technical implementation. What is your actual requirement?

Answer (score 1):

For DLLs, you could put them in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Virtual Directories are an option to share some types of files, although this will not work with DLLs etc.

You can also use [symbolic links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363878(v=vs.85).aspx), to share things like license files, images, JS, CSS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
I have first tried with copying manually the bin and common folder(app_controls) in each publication and it is working.
But above approach has lot of performance issue so I have search and following is my approach.
1)For bin folder I have use the directory junction
2)For app_controls(whcih is common folrder) I have use the virtual directory for the folder withein the application of the each country(publication).
The above is working in my case.Our application is having almost 50 countries(publication)

Thanks,
Khemchand.